# Excel Library - How Does .Net 4.0 Affect It

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package

I'm using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` nuGet library to export an excel report from my application. I noticed that I was receiving the below error running on certain machines. My initial speculation was that there was a mismatch in version number somewhere between the OS or installed version of excel on the machine running the tool. But then when I changed from .Net 3.5 to 4.0 this error went away regardless of OS version or excel version installed.

So I'm up and running but I have been unable to find details of how the updated framework has caused this to suddenly work on all configurations. Out of curiousity, could someone explain or point me in the direction of an explaination?

[image: Error]

Comment: Are you sure you are deploying this dll to your end users? Looks like you may not be, and the code is searching for this in the GAC. On some machines this may not be installed?

Comment: It would suggest that that version of the interop is .net 4 specifi

Answer (score 0):

The `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` package depends on Excel being installed on the machine, since it's just a translator (called an Interop Assembly) to help you talk to Excel. It does not work when Excel is not there to talk to. To have a more robust solution with working with Excel files from code, have a look at [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML).

> ClosedXML makes it easier for developers to create Excel 2007+ (.xlsx, .xlsm, etc) files. It provides a nice object oriented way to manipulate the files (similar to VBA) without dealing with the hassles of XML Documents. It can be used by any .NET language like C# and VisualBasic.NET.